# how to use new into for loop

Tags: objective-c, loops, new-operator

I would like to use new into for loop in objective c 
for example

```
NSMutablearray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]] init];

for (int i=0 ; i< 5; i++){
    [array addObject:[[Direction alloc] initWith:random()];
}
```

When I run it there is only one object and then stop with messages.
but

```
NSMutablearray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]] init];

   Direction * d=  [[Direction alloc] initWith:random()]
   for (int i=0 ; i< 5; i++){
        [array addObject:d];
     [array addObject:d];
     [array addObject:d];
     [array addObject:d];
     [array addObject:d];

    }
```

there is no error.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]] init] autorelease];

NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
for (int i=0 ; i< 5; ++i){
    Direction *direction = [[[Direction alloc] initWith:(arc4random()%100)] autorelease];
    [array addObject:direction];
}
[pool drain];
```

Answer (score 0):

It gives error because your direction object is not released . u are allocing it value evry time loop gose u can do it either two ways

```
 Direction * d=  [[Direction alloc];

For (loop)
{
d=random() // something like this
}
```

or

what the above person said u can autorealase it.